# Getting and error when install pod Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I have been trying to install pod Alamofire to my project using CocoaPods method
the installation was succeed but when I start building the project I got this error. I wasn't do anything after it is installed.

How can I resolve this problem?

[image: this is the image]

**podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'

pod "TSClusterMapView"

pod "MagicalRecord"

pod 'Follower'

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
```

Comment: Have you started the project with the .xcworkspace extension?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?  Can you add the contents of your `Podfile` to your question?

Comment: @RashwanL Yes I started

Comment: @JAL I'm using version 7.2.1 and I have updated my question by adding podfile

Comment: Do you really need source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **Product > Clean** firstly if you didn't do that. If you encounter some problems **make sure your Cocoapods up-to-date.** In addition check your podfile before pod install **target <> do** like below.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
use_frameworks!

target '<ProjectName>' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this error, you should have Swift 2.2 to install the pod.

Check your version with `xcrun swift -version`, if it's < 2.2 you should download Xcode 7.3, that will fix the problem.